# Clear file queue on Jquery file Upload plugin Angularjs Version

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-file-upload

I use the angularjs version of the blueimp file upload plugin.([WebSite](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/))

If I upload files the first time it works , but the second time the plugin upload the file and the first one ...

I saw that the $scope.queue is not reset after upload. There is a clear function but I don't know how to use it.

There is my code :

```
candidats.controller('cvUploadController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $modal, $window, $location, toaster, $timeout) {
  var indexFile = 0;
  $scope.options = {
    url: '/api/CvAPI/',
    autoUpload: false,
    dropZone: $('fileupload'),
    done: function(e, data) {
      $scope.filename = data.result.result;
      $scope.array = $scope.candidat.NiveauEtude.Libelle.split('+');
      $http.put("/api/CvAPI?fileName=" + $scope.filename + "&path=" + $scope.array[0] + "%2B" + $scope.array[1] + "&CandidatID=" + $scope.candidat.ID + "&NomCv=" + $scope.fichiers[indexFile].nom + "&CvID=0" + "&LangueID=" + $scope.fichiers[indexFile].langueID)
        .success(function() {
          $scope.getCvs();
        });
      indexFile++;
      if (indexFile == $scope.fichiers.length) {
        indexFile = 0;
      }
    }
  };
  $scope.$on('fileuploadstop', function(e, data) {
    $scope.getCvs();
    $scope.fichiers = [];
    $scope.queue = [];

  });
  $scope.$on('fileuploadchange', function(e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
      var fichier = {
        nom: file.name.replace(/\.[^\.]*$/, ''),
        langueID: 1
      }
      $scope.fichiers[index] = fichier;
      if (index == data.files.length - 1) {
        $('#CvModal').modal();
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="cvUploadController">
  <form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" file-upload="options" ng-class="{'fileupload-processing': processing() || loadingFiles}">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
      <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}">
                                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                                            <span>Add files...</span>
      <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple ng-disabled="disabled">
      </span>
      <!-- The global file processing state -->
      <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- The global progress state -->
    <div class="col-lg-5 fade" ng-class="{in: active()}">
      <!-- The global progress bar -->
      <div class="progress progress-striped active" file-upload-progress="progress()">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- The extended global progress state -->
      <div class="progress-extended"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="CvModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-top:10px">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Détails Cv</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div ng-repeat="data in fichiers">
            <label>Nom Cv</label>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="fichiers[$index].nom" />
            <br />
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="fichiers[$index].langueID" ng-options="langue.ID as langue.Libelle for langue in languesCv"></select>
            <br />
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()">Annuler</button>
          <a class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="submit()">Valider</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why don't you just clear it on the success callback?

Comment: Why don't you use the file upload directive - https://github.com/DominicBoettger/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: @Moogs the success callback is call after each upload succes right ?
so if I clear the queue at this  moment , the remainings files doesn't get upload.
I just need to know how reset this scope.

Comment: @Donal I've alread tried with this one , same problem. With the official version there is a directive to.